# Why does this program not output anything?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int test = 0;
   cout << (test ? "A String" : 0) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's strange?

Comment: What is it outputting? At least tell us *that*.

Comment: Obviously, you can't cout 0.

Comment: Its printing nothing on screen.

Comment: @vivekjain: Yes, that's to be expected.

Comment: @vivekjain: since `test` is 0, the second half of `?:` is invoked, and both operands of `?:` have to be the same data type, so your code is effectively the same as this: `cout << (char*)0 << endl`, ie empty character data is being written. That is why you do not see anything.

Comment: Not sure what is with the downvotes to be honest, seems like a fair question.  Really just seems like a bunch of bullies ganging up on a well-intentioned less-knowledgeable well-intentioned person in this case.  There are some pretty horrible questions on SO that don't get 7 downvotes.

Comment: why it converts to (char*)0 instead of 0 ?

Comment: @Addy: the output of `?:` has to be a data type that is common to both operands. A `char*` cannot be implicitly converted to an `int`, but a `0`literal can be implicitly converted to `char*`

Comment: Lacks the minimal understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ternary `?:` operator requires both output operands to either be the same data type, or at least convertible to a common data type. A `char*` cannot be implicitly converted to an `int`, but a `0` literal can be implicitly converted to a `char*`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int test = 0;
   std::cout << ((test) ? "A String" : "") << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int test = 0;
   std::cout << ((test) ? "A String" : (char*)0) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

If you are trying to actually output `0` when `test` is 0, then you have to do this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int test = 0;
   std::cout << ((test) ? "A String" : "0") << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, get rid of the `?:` operator since you cannot use it to mix different incompatible data types for output:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int test = 0;
   if (test)
       std::cout << "A String";
   else
       std::cout << 0;
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program compiles just fine. I think OP expects the output to be `0`.

Comment: But the OP's code compiles fine, right?

Comment: The ternary operator does *not* require both output expressions to have the same data type, but it will convert them to a common data type if the two differ.

Comment: @datenwolf, I think the output will be ASCII of `0`.

Comment: why it converts to (char*)0 instead of 0 ?

Comment: @Addy the compiler needs to decide on a common data type to convert `"A string"` and `0` to.  This is because the ternary operator as a whole needs to have a fixed return type: it cannot have different return data types based on the result of evaluating the conditional portion.  In this case it chooses (for whatever internal precedence reasons, etc.) to convert both to `char *`s.